# What are the fonts used in this document?

Tags: fonts

I am really not sure if the following document was created with LaTeX: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4487.pdf

Nevertheless I would be very grateful if someone could guess the name of the fonts used for the headings, the body of the text and the code samples.

Finally how should I proceed to use these same fonts with LaTeX? Thanks!

Comment: The simple answer is that this document uses too many fonts.  The main body font is Garamond, the main mono font is Consolas, and the heading font is Arial-BoldMT while the footnotes and quotations in italics seem to use Times New Roman.  The document also contains Cambria and Gautami (a Windows font for Telegu) although there is no Telegu in document so I suspect this was created using Microsoft Word. But really this is not a style to emulate.

Comment: If it is LateX, somebody has put a lot of effort into emulating Word's uglinesses. Just the bad spacing would require an investment of time and energy.

Comment: @AlanMunnThanks for the feedback. When you say "really this is not a style to emulate" do you mean that too many different fonts are used or do you mean that these fonts should not be used altogether? Would it be OK if I restricted myself to Garamond as the main body/header font and Consolas for the code samples? Of course I would use LaTeX for typesetting the document.